# test if a modal disappears after clicking Delete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, function, jestjs

Beginner with react testing,

I am using jest and react testing library, here I have a component 'A' which is a modal, I'm trying to implement a test to it, when the user clicks a button 'Delete Link' then this modal should disappear(function `onDelete`). As you can see I'm clicking the button using FireEvent.click() so after it when changing `toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0)` from 0 to 1, I'm getting `Expected number of calls: 1 Received number of calls: 0`, shouldn't be expected and received both be 1?

The end component(modal) should not be visible to the user after clicking Delete Link.

Can someone enlighten me with this?
Any suggestions/help is appreciated.

English is not my mother language so there might be mistakes.

my code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, cleanup, fireEvent } from "@testing- 
library/react";
import { LinkForm } from "../forms/LinkForm";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "../../redux/store";

import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";

describe("Testing component", () => {
const onClickCallback = jest.fn();
 test("Testing if link is deleted when button 'Delete Link' is clicked", () => {
const mockDelete = jest.fn();

const props = {
  onDelete: mockDelete,
};

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <LinkForm
      classes={{ button_basic: "", formControl: "" }}
      key={""}
      onSubmit={onClickCallback}
      onCancel={onClickCallback}
      // onClick={onClickCallback()}
      {...props}
    />
  </Provider>
);

const component = screen.getByTestId("LinkForm");

const deleteLinkButton = screen.getByRole("button", {
  name: /Delete Link/i,
});

expect(deleteLinkButton).toBeVisible();
fireEvent.click(deleteLinkButton);

expect(mockDelete).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
expect(component).toBeVisible();
  });
});
```

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { connect, RootStateOrAny, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Trans } from "react-i18next";
import { editLink, changeLink, removeLink } from "../../redux/actions";
import {Button} from "@material-ui/core/";
import { Done, Delete } from "@material-ui/icons";

interface AFormProps {
  key: string;
  onSubmit: () => void;
  onCancel: () => void;
  onClick?: () => void;

  classes: {
    button_basic: string;
    formControl: string;
  };
}

const A: React.FC<AFormProps> = (props) => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    dispatch(editLink(linkSettings));
    externalOnSubmit();
  };

  const onDelete = () => {
    // Delete selected link from graph
    dispatch(removeLink(currentLink.id));
    dispatch(changeLink(""));
  };

  const disabled = currentLink ? false : true;

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} data-testid="LinkForm">

      <Button
        id="delete"
        type="button"
        onClick={onDelete}
        disabled={disabled}
        variant="outlined"
        color="secondary"
        className={classes.button_basic}
        startIcon={<Delete />}
      >
        <Trans i18nKey="form.linkForm.delete">Delete Link</Trans>
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
};

export const LinkForm = connect(null, null)(A);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the test, you are passing a mock function to the `onDelete` prop of the form but this is not defined in `AFormProps` nor is an `onDelete` prop being consumed in the component. The `onDelete` function is created within the component scope and set as the `onClick` for the button. The mock function will never be used in this case.

Comment: thanks for explanation, could you possibly give working test example using my code which does it corectly ? ( when the user clicks a button 'Delete Link' then this modal should disappear)

Comment: To do that, I would need to know what is being done when `dispatch(removeLink(currentLink.id))` and `dispatch(changeLink(""))` is executed.  If those actions will indirectly cause the modal to be hidden, you may be able to run your test without needing a mock function. Just trigger the `onClick` for the button and assert the modal is missing.

Comment: first one: export function removeLink(id: number) {
  return {
    type: ActionType.REMOVE_LINK,
    payload: id,
  };
}       and second one export function changeLink(nextLink: string) {
  return {
    type: ActionType.CHANGE_LINK,
    payload: nextLink,
  };
}   and that modal is used like this const renderLinkForm = () => {
    const linkId = currentLink ? currentLink.id : null;
    return (
      <LinkForm
        key={"linkform" + linkId}
        classes={props.classes}
        onSubmit={closeSettingsPopup}
        onCancel={closeSettingsPopup}
      />);};

Comment: Are you showing all of the code from the `LinkForm` component in your original post? I do not see where `linkSettings` or `currentLink` is defined.

Comment: LinkForm component has much more code, i can give you those what you need but not whole thing here: const currentLink = useSelector( (state: RootStateOrAny) => state.graphArticles.currentLink ); linkSettings comes from useState : const [linkSettings, setLinkSettings] = useState(defaultLinkSettings); and defaultSettings: const defaultLinkSettings = { id: 0, source: 0, target: 1, boundary: { id: 0, points: [], people: [], }, };

Comment: Where is the logic that shows/hides the LinkForm when that button is clicked? All I see in the example component is that if `currentLink` is falsy, then set the `disabled` attribute to `true`. A test for that can be written using [toBeDisabled()](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tobedisabled) if you are using [@testing-library/jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tobedisabled)